# explore sqlite wallet

Tags: wallet.dat, database

I created an sqlite wallet, tried to browse it from the sqlite3 program, but had to reset (tset) the terminal after querying the main table garbled the console characters. How to query the main table while protecting the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data stored is binary data, which is why it comes out garbled. It is not text. So you will have to convert the data to something human readable. One such method is to convert it to hex. One such query to do that is:

```
select hex(key), hex(value) from main;
```